# Convert object to a grouped nested object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, data-conversion

Given a structure like below, I could not get JPA to map DB results into `UserDTO` directly, so I am trying to convert `UserQueryDTO` to `UserDTO` programmatically.

```java
public class UserQueryDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String record;
    private Day day;
    private Hour hour;
}
```

```java
public class UserDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private List<RecordDayHourDTO> recordDayHours;
}

private class RecordDayHourDTO {
   private String record;
   private List<DayHourDTO> dayHours;
}

private class DayHourDTO {
    private Day day;
    private List<Hour> hours;
}
```

So, a result like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john",
    "record": 1,
    "day": 1,
    "hour": 13
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john",
    "record": 1,
    "day": 1,
    "hour": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john",
    "record": 1,
    "day": 5,
    "hour": 9
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john",
    "record": 2,
    "day": 2,
    "hour": 11
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jane",
    "record": 1,
    "day": 1,
    "hour": 23
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jane",
    "record": 2,
    "day": 1,
    "hour": 17
  }
]
```

should become:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john",
    "recordDayHours": [
      {
        "record": 1,
        "dayHours": [
          { "day": 1, "hours": [13, 15] },
          { "day": 5, "hours": [9] }
        ]
      },
      {
        "record": 2,
        "dayHours": [{ "day": 2, "hours": [11] }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jane",
    "recordDayHours": [
      {
        "record": 1,
        "dayHours": [{ "day": 1, "hours": [23] }]
      },
      {
        "record": 2,
        "dayHours": [{ "day": 1, "hours": [17] }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you have an attempt - please share it, it would bring more value to the question. By the way, `Day` and `Hour` are not standard Java date-time classes.

Comment: I haven't attempted solving this yet because the only solution I came up with requires 3-4 nested for loops, but I will attempt to solve it. In the case of `Day` and `Hour`, I had to make these names up because the original code I am working on is much broader so I had to simplify it while keeping the use-case somewhat understandable. In reality, every property is a data entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no chance to map `UserQueryDTO` to `UserDTO` in a concise way because there are too many nested objects.

Attempt to achieve this in a single method will result in unmentionable mess. Hence, I think that the right way to approach this problem would be to extract this logic into a separate class, give the appropriate name to every its piece and document it.

The approach I come up with is to create make use collector `groupingBy()` with *classifier* function which generates an instance of record, holding `id` and `username`, as a *key* and *composite collector* as the *downstream*, which would take care of the `RecordDayHourDTO`. And then iterate over the entries of the *map*, transforming each entry into `UserDTO` object.

The downstream collector in turn comprised of several built-in collectors and a function which internally delegates the job to a couple narrow-focused methods.

```
public class QueryToUserMapper {
    private QueryToUserMapper() {}
    
    public static List<UserDTO> toUserDTO(Collection<UserQueryDTO> queries) {
        
        return queries.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                UserDTOKey::new,
                groupDayHourRecords()
            ))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new UserDTO(entry.getKey().id(), entry.getKey().username(), entry.getValue()))
            .toList();
    }
    
    public record UserDTOKey(Long id, String username){
        public UserDTOKey(UserQueryDTO query) {
            this(query.getId(), query.getUsername());
        }
    }
    
    public static Collector<UserQueryDTO, ?, List<RecordDayHourDTO>> groupDayHourRecords() {
        
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getRecord,
                Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getDay,
                    Collectors.mapping(UserQueryDTO::getHour,
                        Collectors.toList()))),
            QueryToUserMapper::toRecordDayHour
        );
    }
    
    public static List<RecordDayHourDTO> toRecordDayHour(Map<String, Map<Day, List<Hour>>> daysMapByRecordId) {
        
        return daysMapByRecordId.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new RecordDayHourDTO(entry.getKey(), toDayHour(entry.getValue())))
            .toList();
    }
    
    public static List<DayHourDTO> toDayHour(Map<Day, List<Hour>> hoursByDay) {
        
        return hoursByDay.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new DayHourDTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .toList();
    }
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<UserQueryDTO> queries = List.of(
        new UserQueryDTO(1L, "john", "1", new Day(1), new Hour(13)),
        new UserQueryDTO(1L, "john", "1", new Day(1), new Hour(15)),
        new UserQueryDTO(1L, "john", "1", new Day(5), new Hour(9)),
        new UserQueryDTO(1L, "john", "2", new Day(2), new Hour(11)),
        new UserQueryDTO(2L, "jane", "1", new Day(1), new Hour(23)),
        new UserQueryDTO(2L, "jane", "2", new Day(1), new Hour(17))
    );
    
    List<UserDTO> users = toUserDTO(queries);
    
    users.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo - Java 16+*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tRu)

[*A link to Online Demo - Java 8*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tRx)

Comment: This looks incredible, thank you! However, I cannot use `record` keyword because I am on Java 1.8 and, unfortunately, cannot upgrade to 14+

Comment: @ÖzençB. You can easily translate the record into a class (some IDE like IntelliJ  can turn record into a class and visa-versa). I'll add a version of this code fully compliant with **Java 8** in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @ÖzençB. Here it is - [*Java 8 version*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tRx). There are only a few differences between Java 16 code: `toList()` substituted with `collect(Collectors.toList())` and record translated into a class.

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to extend for custom classes. Here, I converted `record` to a class and now it won't group successfully
https://jdoodle.com/a/51PT

Comment: @ÖzençB. Maybe you can show some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Here is an example: https://jdoodle.com/a/51PT
Is it because each record have different references?

Comment: @ÖzençB. You haven't overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, hence your classes can't work properly with hash-based collections.

Comment: @ÖzençB. Pay attention to this version https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tRx every class provided with it's own `equals/hasCode` implementation. You can generate these methods automatically using features of your IDE (you need only pick the right fields). In case if you thought that it's not mandatory based on the 16 version with **records**, then note that every record implicitly has `equals()`, `hashCode()`, getters, `toString()` and canonical constructor (all this boilerplate code gets generated by the compiler).

Comment: @ÖzençB. The main point is that you always need proper `equals/hasCode` implementation while working with such collections like `HashMap` or `HashSet` (collector `groupingBy` internally uses `HashMap`). In case if don't override these methods, default implementation from the `Object` class, which is based on identity comparison using `==` (i.e. `equals` returns `true` when references point to the same object)  would be used.

Comment: Ah, I thought you auto-generated those. It makes so much sense now. I will have to look further into these topics :) Thank you

Comment: @ÖzençB. This topic explained in great depth in the book *"Effective java"* by Joshua Bloch, Items 10 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<UserQueryDTO>>>>> values = userQueryDTOList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getId, Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getRecord, Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getDay, Collectors.groupingBy(UserQueryDTO::getHour)))));
    List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    values.entrySet().stream().forEach(value->{
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setId(value.getKey());
        List<RecordDayHourDTO> recordDayHours = new ArrayList<>();
        value.getValue().entrySet().stream().forEach(record->{
            RecordDayHourDTO recordDayHourDTO = new RecordDayHourDTO();
            recordDayHourDTO.setRecord(record.getKey());
            List<DayHourDTO> dayHourDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
            record.getValue().entrySet().stream().forEach(day->{
                DayHourDTO dayHourDTO = new DayHourDTO();
                dayHourDTO.setDay(day.getKey());
                List<Integer> hours = new ArrayList<>();
                day.getValue().entrySet().stream().forEach(hour->{
                    hours.add(hour.getKey());
                    hour.getValue().stream().forEach(userQueryDTO1 -> {
                        userDTO.setUsername(userQueryDTO1.getUsername());
                    });
                });
                dayHourDTO.setHours(hours);
                dayHourDTOList.add(dayHourDTO);

            });
            recordDayHourDTO.setDayHours(dayHourDTOList);
            recordDayHours.add(recordDayHourDTO);
        });
        userDTO.setRecordDayHours(recordDayHours);
        userDTOList.add(userDTO);

    });
```

First, the level of grouping is done which returns Map<Long, Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List>>>>, and then the mapping to the DTO class is done (There may be an easy way to do the mapping). I hope this is helpful. Also, the Day and Hour variables in the UserQueryDTO are considered Integer.